# Как получить данные с компьютера на сайте используя php? AD авторизацию автоматическую хочу сделать

Tags: php, active-directory

Как получить данные с компьютера на сайте используя php? AD авторизацию автоматическую хочу сделать.

Comment: Кто такие AD и с чем их едят?

Comment: @РустамГимранов Active Directory

Comment: Есть регистрация через форму - тогда нужна просто LDAP библиотека, а есть windows NTLM проброс авторизации (прозрачная авторизация) - тогда нужно установить дополнительные либы к серверу, какие - завитит от того на чём крутится сервер (например проброс AD авторизации апач).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP работает на стороне сервера. Средствами PHP можно только получить данные учетной записи, но не отправить на сервер.

Comment: Как сделать АД авторизацию? мне надо сайт на этот сервак закинуть? где АД хранятся ?

Comment: @anuarthor полагаю, вам нужно узнать, что такое AD и как с ним работать. Смотрите LDAP https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.ldap.php

Comment: Можно отправить на сервер, но так обычно не делают:) http://php.ru/forum/threads/ntlm-php.1327/

Comment: Смотрите вот я зашел в компьютер корпаративный введя туда логин пароль АД учетки и авторизовался, как можно на сайте получить данные АД ?

Comment: @anuarthor пароль нельзя получить из ad, можно попробовать авторизоваться, ad ответит, успешно или нет. Ссылку на документацию дал выше, читайте.